# jQuery UI Datepicker: manual date entry can be incorrect bug

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

No example code here, just a standard jQuery UI datepicker with a minDate and maxDate...

the problem occurs with manual keyboard entry.  If I enter the date in the approved format mm-dd-yyyy and I have my mindate set to -60 (the last 60 days) I can enter a date older than 60 day limit displayed in the datepicker manually with the keyboard.

If I press enter, the mindate gets set correctly, BUT if I tab to the next field on the form (which would be what the standard user would do) the invalid older date stays in the field and can be submitted.

Is there a way to force the date to be checked/corrected in regards to the mindate?  I have seen some validation plugin solutions, but these don't give me access to the mindate that I am aware of.  Or is there a way to disable manual keyboard entry of the date?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mcgrailms answer works and works well.  We did notice some confusion when testing, as clicking in the input box and getting a blinking cursor led to an initial attempt at typing and then confusion over why nothing happened.  What I implemented is this:

On the jQuery UI datepicker I added

```
beforeShow: function() {
  jQuery('#installation_date').css("visibility","hidden")
},

onClose: function() {
  jQuery('#installation_date').css("visibility","visible")
}
```

This gives us a simultaneous appearance of the datepicker, with a hiding of the textbox and then a reappearance of the textbox with the picked date, as soon as the date is picked.  Technically the textbox is still there and input could be entered, but the transition helps guide the user to picking the date from the datepicker.

Answer (score 4):

here is an interesting solution just make the input readonly

like this

```
 <input type="text" class="datepick" readonly="readonly"/>
```

and jquery

```
         $('.datepick').datepicker();
```

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mcgrailm/JHBdd/)**

Comment: mcgrailm that might be a great solution!  how is readonly supported across browsers? pretty well?

Comment: It's supported by all major browsers

Comment: IE5.5+  FF1+  SA1.3+  OP9.2+  CH2+
Full  Full  Full  Full  Full

Comment: Is there a way of stopping this without disabling the ability to type in the date?

Comment: @abe I don't understand your question. In the question the OP had was how to prevent the the user from entering data manually and thats why why I used readonly what exactly do you want to do ?

Comment: Apologies, I meant how can I force a user to input a date within the range of the datepicker's minDate/maxDate without disabling the ability to type in a date. Is there an option I'm missing? I've had to write custom validation rules so far...

Comment: This is a great suggestion, I've been struggling with how to validate user input in a datepicker.  With this method, they can't use any input method _other_ than the datepicker, so that problem simply goes away.  Brilliant!

Comment: @delliottg the only thing i think of that might be a problem with this would be accessibility or if someone has JS turned off (in which case they maybe be up the creek already)

Comment: @mcgrailm, I already test for no JS, as well as offline (it's possible one of our customers can try to run what I'm working on from our published CD, and it absolutely won't work offline).  In both cases I drop them back to our default site so they can simply call us (which is what they currently have to do).